# No graphic card or input devices recognized after 12.10 upgrade (thus useless)

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

My even less non-savvy friend upgraded her system from 12.04 to 12.10 tonight.

After the boot screen, we're faced with these two screens:

[image]
[image]

As the first screen might indicate there's no mouse input working and the keyboard works for getting to the second screen but not further.

The first boot we encountered this issue we hade mouse and keyboard working and thus we got to a weird mixture between console and desktop, but mouse and keyboard failed after that point.

The computer is a [HP G62-A33EO](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02269424&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4226848) laptop with ATI graphics.

How can I get the system working again? (Or if nothing else, save the data that is stored on the drive?)

Comment: @Peachy Thanks! Found neither solution working, sadly.

Comment: Are you dual booted, if so you can choose to boot from a "(Recovery Mode)" version of that kernel in grub. That usually works for me.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Please ask a new question on how to get the data off the drive, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To save the data you have on drive.. :

Create a live CD / USB device ( USB - recommended )

Use this software for this purpose : [UNetBootin software for creating live boot devices](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Boot using the Live USB and using that copy all important data and take backup in some secondary storage device.